# How did my TI-Basic program get corrupted?

Tags: texas-instruments, ti-basic

I wrote a TI-Basic program for my TI-84 Plus. It worked fine when I put it on my calculator, and it worked the next morning too, but a couple hours later I tried running it again and it turned out that some sections had gotten duplicated and overwritten other sections, which erased some labels and stopped most functions from working correctly. I have a backup on my computer, but I want to know how it happened. I have about 21 kB of RAM and over 300 kB of archive memory free, and my batteries are brand new.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to guess about bugs the calculator might have, or mistakes you might have made using it? Unless someone else has seen exactly the same thing happen I'm not sure anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reasons that would lead to this issue are older or mismatched batteries, sudden jolts or shock to the calculator, or not enough free RAM/archive memory. Since it seems like none of these caused your issue, it could perhaps be some type of faulty hardware or poorly written assembly code, from assembly scripts/custom apps.

Glad to hear you had a backup on your computer :)